# how to run two arrays at a time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

Hi friends i am getting following error,if i run php with codeigniter:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 2014 Commands out of sync; you
>   can't run this command now CALL get_sub_menu(3) Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\database\DB_driver.php Line Number: 330

**Controller:**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Learnersway extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('home');
    }
    function index()
    {
         $data['main_menu'] = $this->home->select_main_menu();
         $data2['sub_menu'] = $this->home->select_sub_menu();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->view('home',$data,$data2);

    }
}
?>
```

**NOTE:**

1. if i run both arrays $data and $data2 at a time. i am getting above error.
2. But i can able to run one at a time.

Please tell me how to run both arrays $data and $data2 at a time.

Comment: what do you mean by RUN BOTH ARRAYS... can you show the code where you are RUNNING  both arrays?

Answer (score 3):

just use

```
$data['main_menu'] = $this->home->select_main_menu();
$data['sub_menu'] = $this->home->select_sub_menu();
....
 $this->load->view('home',$data);
```

you can get them in view by

```
print_r($main_menu);
print_r($sub_menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql Error # 2014 means you have started a second query to the database without finishing the first one.

You need to fix your select_main_menu() function to actually fetch the results from the database and close or finish the statement before returning it's results.